# Formatting - at once - all the files in a Visual Studio project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, formatting

I am interested in formatting all the files in a Visual Studio (ver. 2005)  project all at once.

Currently, there is a way to format a single document by doing something like **Edit->Advanced->Format Document**. However, I don't see a single command to format all the files of a project all at once.

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) provides code cleanup and formatting and that is just a fraction of its functionality...

Comment: Just for future reference, be noted that macros have been dropped from [VS 2011](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/d8410838-085b-4647-8c42-e31b669c9f11).

Comment: Phil Haack says: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/05/22/an-obsessive-compulsive-guide-to-source-code-formatting.aspx

Comment: Tim Abell wrote a macro to do this on his blog http://timwise.blogspot.com/2009/01/format-all-document-in-visual-studio.html

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Tim Abell wrote a macro to do this on his [blog](http://timwise.blogspot.com/2009/01/format-all-document-in-visual-studio.html):

> Here's a handy macro script for visual studio I knocked together today.
>   It runs "edit, format document" on every document of the listed file types.
>
> You have to keep an eye on it as it's interactive and does sometimes pop up a message and wait for an answer.
>
> You can get the vb file at https://github.com/timabell/vs-formatter-macro
>   More info at https://github.com/timabell/vs-formatter-macro/wiki

The original code is available at the blog post. Note that this is older than the version available on github above.

Comment: It seems macro support was removed from recent Visual Studio versions.

Answer (score 37):

The [Format All Files](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=munyabe.FormatAllFiles) extension worked for me. Nothing to do, just install and click!

Comment: Anyone reading this who wants only selected file types. Read the extension page and it says how to do it.

Comment: If you're wondering the package is updated for vs2019 despite being 5 years old.

Comment: Doesn't work with Visual Studio 2022 as of now.

Answer (score 29):

If anyone is still interested in this question, Visual Studio 2019 brought this functionality through a feature called [Code Cleanup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/whats-new-visual-studio-2019?view=vs-2019#code-cleanup)!

Just run Code Cleanup for Solution!

And you can also create multiple clean profiles and define which actions happen in each one.

Comment: But do not confuse with Resharper "Cleanup Code..."

Comment: This is the simplest solution in current versions of VS.
You can do it on individual projects too by right-clicking on the project within the Solution Explorer and choosing `Analysis and Code Cleanup -> Run Code Cleanup (Profile 1)`

Comment: This doesn't work with a CMake project under VS 2022, as it is not a solution...

Comment: Great functionnality but dosent format cshtml files

Comment: And as we have come to expect --no, actually, _**demand**_-- from Microsoft, this new "feature" of Visual Studio is only good for demonstration purposes. It seems to work fine if you try it on a tiny solution, but try it on a _**real**_ solution with thousands of source files, and Visual Studio will be frozen for hours.

Answer (score 17):

Note, that the following solution does not work by itself starting with Visual Studio 2015. You need to apply the answer by Marcus Mangelsdorf as well. Then, this script works in Visual Studio 2015 and 2017.

---

Phil Haack outlined a good procedure - [adding a reusable script to indent the project](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/05/22/an-obsessive-compulsive-guide-to-source-code-formatting.aspx/).

## Open your NuGet profile for edition

1. Open the Package Manager;
2. Type `$profile` to see the location of your NuGet profile;
3. Type `mkdir –force (split-path $profile)` to create the profile's folder if it does not exist;
4. Edit the profile with the command `notepad $profile`.

## Add the reusable method to the NuGet profile

Phil used davidfowl's `Format-Document` method which he found at https://gist.github.com/davidfowl/984358:

```
# Function to format all documents based on https://gist.github.com/984353
function Format-Document {
    param(
        [parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        [string[]]$ProjectName
    )
    Process {
        $ProjectName | %{ 
                        Recurse-Project -ProjectName $_ -Action { param($item)
                        if($item.Type -eq 'Folder' -or !$item.Language) {
                            return
                        }

                        $window = $item.ProjectItem.Open('{7651A701-06E5-11D1-8EBD-00A0C90F26EA}')
                        if ($window) {
                            Write-Host "Processing `"$($item.ProjectItem.Name)`""
                            [System.Threading.Thread]::Sleep(100)
                            $window.Activate()
                            $Item.ProjectItem.Document.DTE.ExecuteCommand('Edit.FormatDocument')
                            $Item.ProjectItem.Document.DTE.ExecuteCommand('Edit.RemoveAndSort')
                            $window.Close(1)
                        }
                    }
        }
    }
}

function Recurse-Project {
    param(
        [parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        [string[]]$ProjectName,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]$Action
    )
    Process {
        # Convert project item guid into friendly name
        function Get-Type($kind) {
            switch($kind) {
                '{6BB5F8EE-4483-11D3-8BCF-00C04F8EC28C}' { 'File' }
                '{6BB5F8EF-4483-11D3-8BCF-00C04F8EC28C}' { 'Folder' }
                default { $kind }
            }
        }

        # Convert language guid to friendly name
        function Get-Language($item) {
            if(!$item.FileCodeModel) {
                return $null
            }

            $kind = $item.FileCodeModel.Language
            switch($kind) {
                '{B5E9BD34-6D3E-4B5D-925E-8A43B79820B4}' { 'C#' }
                '{B5E9BD33-6D3E-4B5D-925E-8A43B79820B4}' { 'VB' }
                default { $kind }
            }
        }

        # Walk over all project items running the action on each
        function Recurse-ProjectItems($projectItems, $action) {
            $projectItems | %{
                $obj = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                    ProjectItem = $_
                    Type = Get-Type $_.Kind
                    Language = Get-Language $_
                }

                & $action $obj

                if($_.ProjectItems) {
                    Recurse-ProjectItems $_.ProjectItems $action
                }
            }
        }

        if($ProjectName) {
            $p = Get-Project $ProjectName
        }
        else {
            $p = Get-Project
        }

        $p | %{ Recurse-ProjectItems $_.ProjectItems $Action } 
    }
}

# Statement completion for project names
Register-TabExpansion 'Recurse-Project' @{
    ProjectName = { Get-Project -All | Select -ExpandProperty Name }
}
```

## Reopen Visual Studio to use the command

When you reopen Visual Studio, the command is available.

Simply run it from the NuGet Package Manager Console: `Format-Document` This will re-format all files of the selected project.
To apply to the whole solution, use the command `Get-Project -All | Format-Document`, which lists the projects and then for each of them calls the reformatting command.

As the author put it:

> With this in place, you can now indulge your OCD and run the Format-Document command to clean up your entire solution. I just ran it against <Project> and now can become the whitespace Nazi I’ve always wanted to be.

10/10, would run again.

Comment: @Kristopher for me it worked fine, it traversed all C# files of the multiple projects of my solution, but it is WPF and not ASP.NET . What other folders did you expect it to traverse? Maybe there is an issue with the script that I did not run into.

Comment: I used ReSharper beta to get this done so no worries, but it basically seems to have missed everything else in the solution directory...

Comment: Note that this doesn't work in Visual Studio 2015, see [modulexcite's comment](https://gist.github.com/davidfowl/984358#gistcomment-1807675) on github.

Answer (score 13):

## Additional step needed for Visual Studio 2015

[Phil Haack's solution posted by ANeves](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31537809/2822719) is perfect, but for some reason `$item.FileCodeModel.Language` always returns null in **Visual Studio 2015** making the `Format-Document` skip all files and effectively do nothing.

To (*hackily*) work around this limitation you can replace the `Get-Language` function:

```
# Convert language guid to friendly name
function Get-Language($item) {
    if(!$item.FileCodeModel) {
        return $null
    }

    $kind = $item.FileCodeModel.Language
    switch($kind) {
        '{B5E9BD34-6D3E-4B5D-925E-8A43B79820B4}' { 'C#' }
        '{B5E9BD33-6D3E-4B5D-925E-8A43B79820B4}' { 'VB' }
        default { $kind }
    }
}
```

with the following variant that uses the file's extension instead of the Language GUID:

```
# Convert file extension to friendly language name
function Get-Language($item) {
   if(!$item.FileCodeModel) {
       return $null
   }

   $filename = $item.Name
   $ext = $filename.substring($filename.lastindexof('.'),
                              ($filename.length - $filename.lastindexof('.')))
   switch($ext) {
       '.cs' { 'C#' }
       '.vb' { 'VB' }
       # If you want to prevent re-formatting files that are not VB or C# source files 
       # (e.g. XML files in your project etc.), replace the following line with 
       # "default { $null }" (thanks to HHenn for this suggestion!)
       default { $ext }
   }            
}
```

Comment: I have changed the code in the following way:                                               `switch($ext) {
                    '.cs' { 'C#' }
                    '.vb' { 'VB' }
                    default { $null }
            }` to prevent formatting of none VB or C# files.

Comment: Works on 2017 as well

Answer (score 12):

There's a new way to format all files in a Visual Studio project using the `dotnet` CLI:

1. Install [dotnet format](https://github.com/dotnet/format/) by running the following command:
   `dotnet tool install -g dotnet-format`
2. Run it, replacing `ProjectFile.csproj` with the path to your project file, with the following command line:
   `dotnet format ProjectFile.csproj`

Comment: It does not seem to do `.razor` files nor `.css` files, but it does a good job at what it does. This is of course without me diving into the configuration of it.