# Format every C# code file in VS2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Formatting - at once - all the files in a Visual Studio project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931406/formatting-at-once-all-the-files-in-a-visual-studio-project)

I know that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> will format the entire document.

I have over 100 pages in my project and several projects in the solution.

Is there any easy way for format all documents within the project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some macros to format the entire solution in Visual Studio: [macro1](http://www.kodefuguru.com/post/Format-Solution.aspx), [macro2](http://timwise.blogspot.com/2009/01/format-all-document-in-visual-studio.html).

Pick one.

Answer (score 5):

Do you have [ReSharper](http://jetbrains.com/resharper)? That lets you apply lots of kinds of code cleanup to all files in the solution, including code reformatting, sorting `using` directives and removing unused ones, etc.

It has a bunch of other features too, of course - thoroughly recommended. I don't know of a way of doing it without any VS add-ins though. It's possible that there's a free add-in which has this functionality too, of course.

Comment: Yes, but I was looking for a pure vs solution, since not everyone will have ReSharper

Comment: Everyone *should* have ReSharper.

Comment: bleh, I can't stand resharper. Surprised there is actually something skeet said I don't agree with.