# How can i apply indentation on various files in visual studio 2015?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, indentation, shortcut

I saw on this link [How do you auto format code in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755942/how-do-you-auto-format-code-in-visual-studio) how to apply indentation on files, but I need to apply this in more than 350 files, have a way to do this without open every file?

Comment: See related with solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931406/formatting-at-once-all-the-files-in-a-visual-studio-project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently it is not possible with the default features of the Visual Studio. I was able to accomplish this task using the ReSharper Cleanup Solution feature: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Code_Cleanup__Index.html